# Como Puedo Hacer Un Select Que Dependa De Otro Select con archivo JSON y Jquery

Tags: javascript, html5, json

Este es mi Json

```
var data_depat = [
               {'nombre_dept': 'Categoria 1',
                'id_dept':'1',
                'municipios': [
                   {'id_mun': '1', 'nombre_mun': 'opc 1'}, 
                   {'id_mun': '2', 'nombre_mun': 'opc 2'}, 
                   {'id_mun': '3', 'nombre_mun': 'opc 3'}, 
                ]
               },
               {'nombre_dept': 'Categoria 2',
                'id_dept':'2',
                'municipios': [
                   {'id_mun': '4', 'nombre_mun': 'opc 4'}, 
                   {'id_mun': '5', 'nombre_mun': 'opc 5'}, 
                   {'id_mun': '6', 'nombre_mun': 'opc 6'}, 
                ]
               },
               {'nombre_dept': 'Categoria 3',
                'id_dept':'3',
                'municipios': [
                   {'id_mun': '7', 'nombre_mun': 'opc 7'}, 
                   {'id_mun': '8', 'nombre_mun': 'opc 8'}, 
                   {'id_mun': '9', 'nombre_mun': 'opc 9'}, 
                ]
               },
               {'nombre_dept': 'Categoria 4',
                'id_dept':'4',
                'municipios': [
                   {'id_mun': '10', 'nombre_mun': 'opc 10'}, 
                   {'id_mun': '11', 'nombre_mun': 'opc 11'}, 
                   {'id_mun': '12', 'nombre_mun': 'opc 12'}, 
                ]
               }
             ];
```

---

asi hasta el momento tengo mi html

---

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="es">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>primer ejemplo</title>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/index.js"></script>
                
            </head>
            <body>
                <form>
                        <select name="categorias" id="categoria">
                              <option value=>Categoria 1</option>
                                <option>Categoria 2</option>
                                <option> Categoria 3</option>
                                <option>Categoria 4</option>
                        </select>
                </form>
            



            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Como tienes tu html?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. El título de la pregunta no puede servir para explicar el problema y lo que quieres hacer. Por favor, edita la pregunta explicando qué es lo que ocurre, qué quieres hacer, qué error tienes y qué código estás usando. ¿Crees que podemos entender lo que quieres  poniendo un JSON y diciendo que quieres  *«hacer un select que dependa de otro select»*. Dinos, ¿dónde, cuándo, cómo? ¿qué has probado? ¿qué error tienes? Gracias.

Comment: @JuanKamiloRengifo Stack Overflow no es un foro donde se van posteando más y más cosas para completar la pregunta, Stack Overflow es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas (Q&A) donde la pregunta va en una sección y las respuestas en otra. Si quieres añadir más información debes pulsar en el enlace de [edit] en lugar de escribir respuestas (que no son tales). Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento general del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

yo tengo tres (3) caja de texto

```html
 <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
   <label for="ExampleImputEmail1">* Estado: </label>
    <select class="form-control" id="estado">
     <option selected disabled> Seleccione un Estado</option>
     <?php 
      while ( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($comboestado)) {
       ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $row['estado_id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['estado'] ?></option>

       <?php
      }
      ?>     
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
  <label for="ExampleImputEmail1">* Municipio : </label>
   <select class="form-control" id="municipio" disabled>
    
   </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
  <label for="ExampleImputEmail1">* Parroquia: </label>
   <select class="form-control" id="parroquia" disabled>
    
   </select>
  </div>
```

este ej es de estado municipio y parroquia

el primer combo tiene el php para que traiga todos los estados que tiene tu bd..

los otros dos funcionaran dsd el js con el **id**  se encuentran disabled desde el principio por el js le quitara ese **disabled**

en el js

```js
  $("#estado").change(function(){
    var id=$(this).val();
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "carpeta/carpeta/carpeta/combomunicipio.php",
        data:"id="+id,
        success: function(html){
           $("#municipio").html(html);
           $("#municipio").removeAttr("disabled");
      }
      });
  });
```

tenemos la funcion tipo **change** que habilitara (cambiara) el estado de tu primer combo en este caso municipio o sea al elegir un estado un municipio se habilitara

```html
<?php
include ('conexion.php');
$id= $_POST['id'];
$combociudad = $bd->query("SELECT * from municipio where estado_id_estado='$id'");
?>
<option selected disabled>Seleccione un Munucipioo</option>
              <?php
                  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($combociudad)) {
                    ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $row['municipio_id']?>"><?php echo $row['municipio']?></option>
                    <?php
                  }
                ?>
```

en un archivo php aparte creamos el cod  que tendra el combo dependiente de todos los municipios

para cuando elijamos un estado desde el js q hicimos se ejecute la habilitacion del campo y me muestre el php que traera el segundo combolist con los municipios del estado elegido

como reacciona lo dependiente ??

en tu bd debes de tener  tres tabla .. **estado** **municipio** **parroquia**

cada uno con su id el nombre y el id de de la tabla relacionada ej:

la tabla municipio tendra 3 campos

municipio_id / municipio / id_estado_id

cual es la funcion de ellas tres ?  el municipio ajuro tendra su id ... el campo **municipio** tendra el nombre de dicho municipio y el campo **id_estado_id** es el **id** del estado con el q esta relacionado  ...

ejemplo el  estado ..  **ROJO** es id **1** en su tabla ... el municipio **oscuro** .. es el id en su  tabla... y este estado y municipio estan relacionados .. entonces serian algo asi :

municipio_id = 1

estado = rojo

id_stado_id=  1

municipio_id = 2

estado = azul

id_stado_id=  2

la tabla estado seria

estado_id = 1

estado =rojo

estado_id = 2

estado = azul

obviamente tu registraste 'x' cantidad de municipios .. relacionadas con 'x' estado ...  1 estado puede tener 50 municipios y otro solo 10 ... cuando elijas  el estado con el id **1** el te traerà todos los muicipios q tengan el id_estado_id  **1**

y cuando elijas el estado **2** el te traerà todos los municipios que tengan el id_estado_id **2**